# Print specific Exif image data values with exiv2

Tags: shell, exif, exiv2

How do I print the image Exif date with a tool like `exiv2`?

My goal is to write the image year and month into separate variables. Do I really have to parse the output with regex or is there a alternative to something like this:

```
exiv2 DSC_01234.NEF -ps | grep 'Image timestamp' | ...regex to parse the date
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `-g` flag to output only the property you're interested in, and `-Pv` to print the value without any surrounding fluff. The result is easy to parse.

```
IFS=': '
set $(exiv2 -g Exif.Image.DateTime -Pv DSC_01234.NEF)
unset IFS
year=$1 month=$2 day=$3 hour=$4 minute=$5 second=$6
```

It may also be helpful to change the file date to match the image date: `exiv2 -T DSC_01234.NEF`.

Comment: That's perfect. I'm trying to improve my bash knowledge while writing a script that creates date based folders for the images and renames the files appropriately like you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
OIFS=$IFS; IFS=': '
set -- $(exiv2 -g Exif.Image.DateTime -Pv DSC_01234.NEF)
IFS=$OIFS;
year=$1; month=$2; day=$3; hour=$4; minute=$5; second=$6;
echo "$year:$month:$day $hour:$minute:$second"
```